# How can we design this one?

Tags: automata, finite-automata

Design a DFA to recognize string over Σ = {0,1} that *contains AT LEAST two zeros at its last three positions.*

Comment: In other words, what have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following automata should do. In blue I indicated how the tail segment of our word looks like at this particular node and the node in the top left is our starting point (which I forgot to mark as such). [image: DFA]

Comment: I think that works, although a smaller automata seems possible (not that this was asked).

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD There may very well be a prettier (and planar) solution. The one above is the "I'm pretty sure I can figure this out in one try, so let's use black ink"-version ;-)